# JTextArea и строки

Tags: java, строки, swing

У меня есть обьект JTextArea - лог чата. Я с помощью setText(); отправляю в лог чата отправленные пользователями сообщения. За весь текст лога отвечает текстовая переменная, соответственно все сообщения выводятся не с новой строки а в одну линию. Подскажите как пофиксить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в конце каждого добавления текста добавляйте '\n' в конец строки.
И лучше добавляйте текст методом append() вместо setText()

Comment: Добавлю что для  винды  \r \n, для unix \n, для mac \r

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте между сообщениями символ перевода строки.

Например, так:

```
String text = "1" + "\n" + "2";
```

или так:

```
String text = "1" + System.lineSeparator() + "2";
```

В итоге единица и двойка будут на разных строках.